# Show that $N(\gcd(\alpha,\beta))$ divides $\gcd(N(\alpha),(N(\beta))$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\alpha$,$\beta\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I want to show $N(\gcd(\alpha,\beta))$ divides $\gcd(N(\alpha),(N(\beta))$.

Let $\alpha=a+bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$

Let $\beta=c+di$ where $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$

Then $N(\gcd(\alpha,\beta))=N(u\alpha+v\beta)$ where $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}$

$=N(u(a+bi)+v(c+di))=N(ua+ubi+vc+vdi)=N((ua+vc)+i(ub+cd))=(ua+vc)^2+(ub+cd)^2$

Also $\gcd(N(\alpha),N(\beta))=\gcd(a^2+b^2,c^2+d^2)=x(a^2+b^2)+y(c^2+d^2)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$

At this stage I cannot show $N(\gcd(\alpha,\beta))\mid\gcd(N(\alpha),(N(\beta))$. Any tips on how to go further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One property of the norm is that if $\alpha$ divides $\gamma$, then $N(\alpha)$ divides $N(\gamma)$. So
if $\delta$ is a greatest common divisor of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $N(\delta)$ divides $N(\alpha)$ and $N(\beta)$, so $N(\delta)$ divides $gcd(N(\alpha), N(\beta))$. Hence we are done. For several examples and more on Gaussian integers see the beautiful notes of [K. Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf).